# Why doesn't nodetool work on my Cassandra Cluster?

Tags: configuration, monitoring, cassandra

I have never been able to get nodetool to operate correctly to give me information about my cluster.  We have a simple 3-node cluster of Cassandra 3.11.1 nodes running under CentOS 7.3 -- using the gossip snitch and replication.  We have a special place on the file system where we're putting the node configurations, but these are appropriately set with environment variables.  A "generic" configuration is in the environment for client applications.

These are attempts at using nodetool (I have replaced the exact server name with /hostname/.)

```
  % nodetool -h /hostname/ status
  nodetool: Found unexpected parameters: [/hostname/, status]
  See 'nodetool help' or 'nodetool help '.
```

maybe the help is wrong and flags go at the end?  Running this:

```
  % nodetool  status -h /hostname/
```

gives me usage information.

My favorite is this:

```
  % nodetool help status
  nodetool: For input string: "help"
  See 'nodetool help' or 'nodetool help '.
```

I can connect with cqlsh.  I get the same response from nodetool whether I'm on a remote host or one of the cluster nodes.  Python clients connect fine and we've been able to create keyspaces and bulk load data from remote hosts.

I am sure there is some configuration I have overlooked but I can't find any information about what it might be in the docs.

Any suggestions on how to get nodetool working?

Comment: How did you install Cassandra? Via package or tarball?

Comment: tarball installation

Comment: If you execute `ls -ls `which nodetool`` (`which nodetool` should be back quotes) - does it point to location of this tarball installation?

Comment: Yes.  The nodetool is in the same bin directory as the "cassandra" launch script that is being used - this is the nodetool being found on the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tinkering I figured it out; posting here to close the topic and to help others.

All the scripts in the conf/ directory work in concert and there are a number of environment variables you need to redirect if you install in a non-standard place (i.e. a tarball installation).

For each node in our cluster, we're (now) using:
  (1) cassandra-env.sh
  (2) cassandra-rackdc.properties
  (3) cassandra.yaml
  (4) jvm.options

All the other configuration files are pointed back to the conf/ directory from the tarball using an environment variable.

(2) and (3) set the properties of the node, such as its name, turning on gossip, etc:

(1) and (4) are used by the cassandra bash script when it launches -- the script goes looking for additional configuration files.  We've set it so that the cassandra.in.sh is found in the install area; but previously (1) and (4) were not being found, and these are required to activate JMX, port 7199, which nodetool uses to connect to the cluster.